# How do I apply the Newton method to solve nonlinear equations when the number of variables is not equal to the number of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Given a nonlinear mapping $F:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, I want to solve the following equation:
$$
F(x) = 0. 
$$
However, the Newton method can not be applied to the equation because that the Jacobian matrix is not a square matrix.

Comment: If $ m \lt n $, you can use the pseudoinverse to find the update for vector $x$.

Comment: You can apply the method on $F'(x)F(x)=0$